# % прошедших дней между двумя датами

Tags: php, дата

Ребят подскажите как составит правильно запрос и формулу!
Есть начальная дата например 20,02,2016 и конечная например 30,02,2016.
Нужно вычислить % прошедших дней если сейчас например 25,02,2016 (понятно что это 50%).
Подскажите формулу для php

Comment: 30 февраля? Оригинально. :)

Comment: да это не важно, от балды написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
<?php
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y','01.06.2016');
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y','30.06.2016');
$currentDate = new DateTime();


$startEndDiff = $endDate->diff($startDate);
$startCurrentDiff = $currentDate->diff($startDate);

$passedPercent = round(($startCurrentDiff->days*100)/$startEndDiff->days,2);

echo $passedPercent."%\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище - то что нужно!

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl все ж этот вариант? хм.... беда-а-а...

Comment: По-моему это слишком много кода, для простого действия

Comment: Ну первые 2 строки беруться из бд, а дальше сравнение и вс, так что не подходит

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl  если у тебя в первых двух строках данные идут из базы, то вероятней всего - там они хранятся в формате **Y-m-d**, в таком случае код будет еще проще - `new DateTime($startDateFromDB);`

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 20, 2016);
$finish = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 30, 2016);
$now = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 25, 2016);

$persent = ($finish - $now) / ($finish - $begin) * 100;
echo sprintf("%02.1f%%", $persent);
```

Comment: Але улю. зачем такие сложности? `$datetime1 = date_create('20.02.2016');
$datetime2 = date_create('28.02.2016');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a дней');`   http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php   ................ или `$date1 = strtotime('20.02.2016');
$date2 = strtotime('28.02.2016');
echo ($date2 - $date1) / (3600 * 24) ;`